# Sessão, seção, cessão?

Tags: gramática, ortografia

Qual a diferença entre esses três termos. Quando devo utiliza-los?

What is the difference between these three terms. When should I use them?

Comment: Pena que faltou o secção na pergunta (de seccionar)

Answer (score 4):

**Sessão:** Reunião de pessoas para assistir a um debate, um filme, etc. É interessante notar que essa palavra vem do latim *sessio*, que é relativo a "sentar".

**Seção:** Repartição; departamento.

**Cessão:** Ato ou efeito de ceder.

Comment: No português de Portugal não temos _seção_, mas sim _secção_.

Answer (score 3):

- `Sessão`: session, meeting, duration of certain event
- `Seção`: section, part, division, slice
- `Cessão`: cession, renounce, surrender, assignement, task